# i wanna check if any of my 35 text fields had a value then it color would change

Tags: java, swing

is there a loop for each I can use as array 
as if the value changed that will change the color and if else then color will be back to normal

btw i am really new in java

```
private void bt1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{
    if  (txt1.getText().equals("6652") ) {
        txt1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    } 
    if  (txt2.getText().equals("6652") ) {
        txt2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    } 
    if  (txt3.getText().equals("6652") ) {
        txt3.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about but if you have an array, say `JTextField[] textfields` then iterating over them would be done like `for( JTextField txt : textfields) { ... } `.

Comment: Btw, " i am really new in java" - you might want to delay messing with UI a bit and get a grasp of the basics first. You'll save yourself a few headaches that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could a structure of data where you associate a `JTextField` to a `String`.

You could use a `Map<JTextField, String>` object :

```
    Map<JTextField, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    // add elements in
    map.put(textField1, "6652");
    map.put(textField2, "1142");
    map.put(textField3, "2231");
    ...    

    private void bt1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
      // iterate on it
      for (Entry<JTextField, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
          JTextField field = entry.getKey();
          String value = entry.getValue();
          if (field.getText().equals(value)) {
              field.setBackground(Color.yellow);
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: It worked thanx i had to make it all inside the bt1 click event

Comment: how about if 'TextField 1' has more options like it could be 
 ' "6652","1142","2231","0112","3225" , "6030" ' ,,  and it applied for all 'TextField'

Comment: You are welcome :) In this case, you could add them in a `List<String>` and use the `boolean List.contains(Object o)` instance method to check if the `String` is contained in.

Comment: It could make the question and the accepted answer unclear for users that read the post if I edit my answer to address  another requirement. It is preferable that you open a new question about it.

Answer (score 1):

You should generate the textboxes from an iterable of model objects. That way, you have full control over all textboxes generated. For this scenario, davidxx's answer is much better, but since you are a beginner ...

You can have two arrays

```
TextBox[] tbs = new TextBox[35];
String[] vals = new String[];


public void initStrings()
{
    // fill vals here, manually or automatically
}


public void setProperties(String[] vals1)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < tbs.length; i++)
    {
        tbs[i] = new TextBox();
        vals[i] = vals1[i];
        // Do more with your textbox here
    }
}


public void refreshTextBoxes()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < tbs.length; i++)
    {
        if (tbs[i].getText().equals(vals[i])
        {
             tbs[i].setBackground(Color.yellow);
        }
    }
}

private void bt1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{
    refreshTextBoxes();
    // Do more here, if you like.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save all the Text Boxes in an List of Text Boxes and then you can loop through all of them to update them. Like this.

```
List<TextBox> text_boxes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then add all the Text boxes you want to check like this,

```
text_boxes.add(text_box1);
text_boxes.add(text_box2);
 ...
text_boxes.add(text_box34);
```

Then have a method to change the value of a text box that matches the condition like this

```
private void changeColor(TextBox tex1) 
{
    if  (txt1.getText().equals("6652") ) {
    txt1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
} 
if  (txt2.getText().equals("1142") ) {
    txt2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
} 
if  (txt3.getText().equals("2231") ) {
    txt3.setBackground(Color.yellow);
  }
 }
```

Then in the clicked handler of the button you can loop through all the text boxes to update the color

```
private void bt1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
  {
     //loop through the list
     for (TextBox text_box : text_boxes) {
           changeColor(text_box);
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

string [] txtfield = {"1122","2231","3344"} and use it in a loop